# Segmentation Fault in binary search insertion c++

Tags: c++, c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Segmentaion fault is given in insertion of value in Binary Search tree.
This is hackerrank problem so only this method has to written 
This is what I have written

```
typedef struct node
{
 int data;
 node * left;
 node * right;
}node;

node * insert(node * root, int value)
{
 node* temp = root;
 node* temp1 = new node();
 node* prev = NULL ;
 while(temp != NULL){
    prev= temp;

      if(value >= temp->data)
        temp = temp->right;
      else
        temp = temp->left;
  }
  temp1->data = value;
  temp1->left = NULL;
  temp1->right = NULL;
  if(prev->data >= value)
    prev->left = temp1;
  else
    prev->right = temp1;
 return root;
}
```

I am not getting why this code gives me segmentation fault.

All suggestions are welcomed..

Comment: This should be tagged C, not C++

Comment: @kebs since when is `new` a valid c keyword.

Comment: @Suraj Palwe: Please include all relevant code, not just one snippet.

Comment: @Mark Jansen Oops, sorry, missed that ! I said that because of the `typedef struct ...` that had a strong C smell.

Comment: @MarkJansen this is hacker rank problem where I have to write only this method!!

Comment: @SurajPalwe May i suggest a very simple and clean method.

Comment: @Sumeet Don't bother. Question will be closed anyway. `I am not getting why this code gives me segmentation fault` -> use debugger.

Comment: If your `root` is `NULL`, then the program will never enter the `while` loop, resulting in `prev` never being assigned and a `NULL` pointer being dereferenced in this statement: `if(prev->data >= value)`

Comment: @SurajPalwe Hope it helps.

Comment: @SurajPalwe If you want to solve tree questions on hackerrank,I suggest that get used to recursive techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to make the code complicated when it can be made simpler using recursion.

```
node * insert(node * root, int value)
{
 if(root==NULL)
 {
  root=new node;
  root->data=value;
  root->left=NULL;
  root->right=NULL;
  return root;
 }
 else if(root->data>value)
 {
  root->left=insert(root->left,value);
  return root;
 }
 else 
 {
  root->right=insert(root->right,value);
  return root;
 }    
}
```

Comment: No need for `else` after `if` clause ends with `return`. And if you drop the first `else` you can move the second and third `return` outside the `if–else`.

Comment: Thanks for the recursion, this seems good way to solve

Comment: Function calls are pretty expensive compared to looping and BSTs can get pretty tall. If you want to go the recursive route make sure it's [tail recursive](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TailRecursion). I don't think this implementation is tail recursive.

Comment: @anonymouscoward No, it's not. But it can be made by using a pointer-to-pointer, say `struct node** nest`, which is initialized as `nest = &root`, then slides down the tree by `nest = &((*nest)->left);` and `nest = &((*nest)->right);`. Once you find `*nest == NULL` you graft a new leaf there by `*nest = MakeNewNode(str);`

Answer (score 1):

You do not check for `root == NULL`.

Comment: Thanks I considered that list will always have data .. my bad (:

Comment: @SurajPalwe Dynamic structures often have no data until the first insert... Of course you may pre-allocate some data when creating the structure (for example a list may have a 'head' node, not just a head pointer, and a tree may have a root node, which is by default 'less than' all subsequent nodes added), but usually they are truly empty at start. So generally if the pointer comes from some outer world, always test if it is valid before you use it (unless a caller guarantees the pointer is always valid).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed abd helpful explanation. ..